# show that for every $y$ the sequence $(\|\phi_{x_{n}}(y) \|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces, solution-verification, riesz-representation-theorem

Here is the question and its solution (a solution given to me by Keefer):

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be an unbounded sequence in Hilbert $\mathcal{H}.$ Prove that there exists a vector $x \in \mathcal{H}$ such that the sequence $\{\langle x_{n}, x \rangle\}$ is unbounded.

**Solution:**

Fixed answer: Suppose for every $x \in \mathcal{H}$, $(x,x_n)$ is bounded. Then for the linear functionals $\phi_{x_n}$ given by $\phi_{x_n}(y) = (y,x_n)$, we have for each $y \in \mathcal{H}$, $\sup_n |\phi_{x_n}(y)| < \infty$. Then by the uniform boundedness principle $\sup_n \|\phi_{x_n}\| < \infty$. But $\|\phi_{x_n}\| = \|x_n\|$, so $\sup_n \|x_n\| < \infty$. So $x_n$ is bounded.

**My questions about the solution:**

1- It is not very clear for me why the linear functional $\phi_{x_{n}}$ is defined as thought and what is the new variable $y$ (I was trying to compare what is $h$ in the statement of RRT and what is $x$ there)? I am a little bit confused. I know the solution is trying to use Riesz FrechetRepresentation theorem given below:

> [image]

2- I do not know why in the solution: $\sup_n |\phi_{x_n}(y)| < \infty$ is it by Riesz representation theorem because $\|T(h)\| = \|h\|$ but in the RRT we have $T$ and $T_{h}.$ why if $T$ is isometric that means that $\|T(h)\| = \|h\|$?

3-For the application of the uniform bounded principle for $\phi_{x_n}(y) = (y,x_n)$:

I know that $\phi_{x_n}$ is bounded by our assumption as we are assuming the contrapositive. but how is for  every $y$ the sequence  $(\|\phi_{x_{n}}(y) \|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded? Is this because of the definition of the inner product by means of the norm? I do not know, could anyone explain this for me please?

Could anyone help me in answering this questions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Riesz Representation Theorem (which shows that every linear functional on a Hilbert space is of that form; you don't need that here, as the functionals are constructed explicitly).

A linear functional is a functional that takes an element in $H$ and gives you a number, in a linear way. A function needs an argument, which in the answer you quote was named $y$. So, for each $n$, one is defining the function $\phi_n:y\longmapsto \langle y,x_n\rangle$. This is trivially linear:
$$
\phi_n(y_1+y_2)=\langle (\alpha y_1+y_2),x_n\rangle=\alpha\langle y_1,x_n\rangle+\langle y_2,x_n\rangle=\alpha\phi_n(y_1)+\phi_n(y_2).
$$
And bounded: by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
|\phi_n(y)|=|\langle y,x_n\rangle\leq\|x_n\|\,\|y\|,\ \ \ \ \ y\in H. 
$$

In the answer, $\langle x,x_n\rangle$ is assumed bounded. Because one is proving the contrapositive: you want "$\{x_n\}$ unbounded implies that there exists $x$ with $\{\langle x,x_n\rangle\}$ unbounded", and its contrapositive is "if $\{\langle x,x_n\rangle\}$ is bounded for all $x$, then $\{x_n\}$ is bounded".

So, the assumption for the contrapositive is that $\sup_n\{|\langle x,x_n\rangle|\}<\infty$.  That's precisely $\sup_n |\phi_n(x)|<\infty$. Then the UBP gives you that $\sup_n|\phi_n|<\infty$. And now you use that $\|\phi_n\|=\|x_n\|$ (it's an easy exercise, but you can get it from the Riesz Representation Theorem if you want).

Comment: What about my question about the second requirement to apply UBP (3)?

Comment: That's precisely the assumption, for the proof,  that $\{\langle x,x_n\rangle\}$ is bounded.

Comment: Could you please explain this line  "So, the assumption for the contrapositive is that $\sup_n\{|\langle x,x_n\rangle|\}<\infty$.  That's precisely $\sup_n |\phi_n(x)|<\infty$." by words ….. are you saying that for a sequence to be bounded each element of it must be bounded?

Comment: but the assumption does not contain the norm at every y.we need at every $y$  the sequence of norms $(\|\phi_{x_{n}}(y) \|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  to be bounded ….. the assumption is $\phi_{x_{n}}$ itself is bounded.

Comment: Is it because the norm of the inner product is just the absolute value?

Comment: the last equality I can get it from RRT directly with checking any assumptions?

Comment: I guess. Not sure what "assumptions" you would check.

Comment: What about my above trivial questions?

Comment: what about the relationship between $T$ and $T_{h}$?

Comment: $T$ is the map that maps $h$ to $T_h$. You are making this too complicated. You don't need the Riesz Representation Theorem here. What you need is that the norm of the functional $y\longmapsto \langle y,x\rangle$ is $\|x\|$. You don't need a theorem for that: it's an easy exercise.